# unselectable node in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have TreeView control on winform. I desire to make several nodes unselectable. How can I achive this.
There is only one idea in my mind - custom drawn nodes, but may be more easier way exists? Please advice me

I have already try such code in `BeforeSelect` event handler:

```
private void treeViewServers_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Node.Parent != null)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

But effect it gained is not appropriate. Node temporary get selection when I am holding left mouse button on it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could completely disable mouse events in case you click on a not-selectable node.

To do this, you have to override `TreeView` a shown in the following code

```
public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201; //513
    int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202; //514
    int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203; //515

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN ||
           m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP ||
           m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            //Get cursor position(in client coordinates)
            Int16 x = (Int16)m.LParam;
            Int16 y = (Int16)((int)m.LParam >> 16);

            // get infos about the location that will be clicked
            var info = this.HitTest(x, y);

            // if the location is a node
            if (info.Node != null)
            {
                // if is not a root disable any click event
                if(info.Node.Parent != null)
                    return;//Dont dispatch message
            }
        }

        //Dispatch as usual
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! I also add filtration for right button and now my tree view works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: What if the user selects the node by using key board (up,down,left,right) keys

Comment: The code in my post just cancel the selection in case of mouse clicks, that is not handled by the code in the question. But for the keyboard keys selection, is enough to Cancel the event in treeViewServers_BeforeSelect event (or in the OnBeforeSelect if you override it). Of course you need to combine both codes to completely avoid the selection.